# How to add relative number of list as title with lapply

Tags: r, plot, lapply

I have this as reprex to let you understand what I am trying to do

```
mtcar = mtcars[-11]
examples = list(mtcars, mtcar)

lapply(examples, function (x){
  plot(density(x$mpg), main = 
         paste0('Graph for ', ' (', ')'))
})
```

I would like each graph would appear in brackets with the related number of the list that graph is represented from. Therefore, the graph from the first list would have in the brackets number 1 and the second one, number 2.

How could I possibly properly modify the code ?
Thanks

Comment: Don't apply directly to the list - apply to a counter and use the counter to index the list AND to paste into your title:  `lapply(c(1:length(examples), function(x) { plot(density(examples[x]$mpg ....`

Comment: Could you please provide the whole code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Map` instead of `lapply`:

```
Map(
  function (x, i) {
    plot(density(x$mpg), main = paste0('Graph for (', i, ')'))
  },
  examples, seq_along(examples)
)
```

Comment: Thnak you. I am still learning how to use this iterative fucntions. Does the lapply function not take the x and y argument like function Map?

Comment: @12666727b9 No: `lapply` only iterates over a single vector/list, and so the function you pass to it can only have a single argument. By contrast, `Map` is a general form of `lapply` which can iterate over more than one vector/list in parallel, and the function you pass to it receives the current element from each of the input vectors/lists.